# Who was Yalta's father?

Tags: women, historical-figures, maseches-gitin

In [Gittin 67b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Gittin.67b.17.1?lang=en) Yalta is identified by Rashi as the daughter of the Nasi/Exilarch. Since she was married to the 3rd generation Babylonian Amora Rav Nachman (as per brachot 51b) I assume she was born after 250 CE. I would like to know if any works identify her father explicitly by name.

Answer (score 5):

[Toldos Amoraim V'Tanaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43958&st=&pgnum=98&hilite=) brings a view from Sefer Hadoros that Yalta was the daughter of Raba bar Avu'ah "רבה בר אבוה". Although there are those that dismiss this view, they do not offer an alternative named person.